# Matlab pixel coordinates

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D image. I would like to find the coordinates of the pixels of the image. and then using these coordinates go back to the original image

```
%x = imread('y.jpg');
[r c] = find(x);
%
```

Now I have the coordinates. Is there a way to use these coordinates to get the image back, excluding the zero terms of the original image?

Comment: Can you clarify what you wish to achieve ?  Your last sentence doesn't quite make sense to me. If you exclude any pixels, you will not get an 'image' back because it's unlikely to be a matrix again now that it loses some elements.

Comment: Check [`sub2ind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html). Or use `find` with a single output (linear index)